# How to fetch the client Ip address along with language and Country using Angularjs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to fetch the client ip address, country and Language from the server. I had written my code like this in controller.

```
setDefaultEnglish();
      function setDefaultEnglish() {
        var url = "//freegeoip.net/json/";
         $http.get(url).then(function(response){
    });
```

This is giving me ip address and country name. I also need language along with these two. 
Kindly help

Comment: Try to use $(document).ready( function() { $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?", function(data){ alert( data.host); } );};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JS function to get the browser language.
reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_language.asp

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var userLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
console.log(userLanguage);
</script>
```